# Why do the Spark examples fail to spark-submit on EC2 with spark-ec2 scripts?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I downloaded spark-1.5.2 and I setup a cluster on ec2 using the [spark-ec2 doc here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html).

After that I went to `examples/` and run `mvn package` and packaged the examples in a jar.

In the end I run the submit with:

```
bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaTC --master spark://url_here.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7077 --deploy-mode cluster /home/aki/Projects/spark-1.5.2/examples/target/spark-examples_2.10-1.5.2.jar
```

Instead of it running, I get the error:

```
WARN RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server spark://url_here.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7077.
Warning: Master endpoint spark://url_here.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7077 was not a REST server. Falling back to legacy submission gateway instead.
15/12/22 17:36:07 WARN Utils: Your hostname, aki-linux resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.10.63 instead (on interface wlp4s0)
15/12/22 17:36:07 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
15/12/22 17:36:07 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.lookupTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcEnv.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcEnv.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcEnv.scala:225)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcEnv.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client$.main(Client.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcEnv.scala:241)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Can you access http://url_here.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080? Can you `telnet url_here.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 7077`? Can you include a screenshot of the welcome page of the standalone master? What's in the logs of the master?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I eventually gave up and copied over the jar to the master and run it in the default mode client.

Comment: Are you still able to recreate the issue? I'd like to have a solution for this not a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the URL to master contains "url-here"?

spark://url_here.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7077

Or maybe you are trying to obfuscate it for this post.

If you can you connect the Spark UI at 
http://url_here.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:4040 or depending on your spark version http://url_here.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080, make sure you are using the URL variable seen on the Spark UI for your spark://...:7070 command line argument

Comment: It is definitely the same URL copy-pasted from the Spark UI, I am obfuscating for this post.